# why does this code execute my function soon as the document is loaded?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why this code below executes my function as soon as the document is loaded:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
function yep() {
    window.alert('yep');
}
list[0].onclick = yep();
```

But this does not:

```
list[0].onclick = yep;
```

Why does `()` make a difference when executing a function in this situation?

Comment: The `()`  is how a function is invoked. Just like your `alert('yep')` is doing except no argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parenthesis `()` execute function immediately. On your second line you are assigning the value of `list[0].onclick` to the function name but not executing it.

Answer (score 1):

Putting `()` after a reference to a function means that you want to call the function. Leaving them off means you just want to work with the *reference* to the function as a value in and of itself.

Answer (score 1):

`yep` is a reference to a function.

`yep()` is a directive telling the Javascript engine to execute the `yep` function.

That's why one executes immediately and the other does not.